# WPF DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn not triggered reliably

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I use a WPF [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=netframework-4.6.1) whose ItemsSource is bound to some `MyResults` property, where `MyResults` is the DefaultView of a [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.6.1) instance.
As I need some flexibility in labeling the column headers in the DataGrid, I subscribe the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event to adjust these headers.

View/XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ResultTable" ItemsSource="{Binding MyResults, Mode=OneWay}"
  cal:Message.Attach="[Event AutoGeneratingColumn] = [Action CustomizeAutoColumn($this, $eventArgs)]"
  AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
```

ViewModel/CS:

```
public DataView MyResults { get { return MyDataTable.DefaultView; } }

public void CustomizeAutoColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e) {
    e.Column.Header = AdjustHeaderText(e.Column.Header);
}
```

The number of columns in `MyDataTable` may change dynamically, requiring the DataGrid to update its auto-generated columns.
In that case, the following function in the ViewModel (`Caliburn.Micro.Screen` subclass) is triggered:

```
private void UpdateResultTable() { // not working
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MyResults);
}
```

My problem is that the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event is never fired with this implementation (or at least `CustomizeAutoColumn` is never called).
Neither during program initialization (which is my first problem), nor on calling `UpdateResultTable` (the second problem).
While new row content is added to the view as expected, the columns remain as they are.

I found a workaround by getting a handle to the View object in my ViewModel, explicitly resetting the items source.
However this is evidently quite ugly, especially since it breaks View/ViewModel separation.
Note that since I'm using Caliburn Micro, I don't have any code-behind for the view XAML.

```
private void UpdateResultTable() { // working
    var datagrid = VisualTree.FindChild<DataGrid>((DependencyObject)GetView(), "ResultTable");
    datagrid.ItemsSource = null;
    datagrid.ItemsSource = MyResults;
}
```

Any ideas how to get the initial approach to work?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

> explicitly resetting the items source. However this is evidently quite ugly, especially since it breaks View/ViewModel separation.

Not ugly per-se but required.

But to adhere to such separation, have the VM provide a command (`ICommand`) that requests that the view reset the datacontext, which is subscribed to by the view. Hence separate.

I have done it for the same reasons and here is the code to do a reset from a requested change by the VM:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    DataContext = VM = new CertifyingVM();

    VM.CommandRefreshBindings = new OperationCommand(o =>
    {
        MainAccessionHeader.DataContext =
        MainHeader.DataContext = null;

        MainAccessionHeader.DataContext =
        MainHeader.DataContext = VM;

        var currentBatch = VM.CurrentBatch;
        MainAccessionHeader.CurrentBatch = null;
        MainAccessionHeader.CurrentBatch = currentBatch;

    });

    VM.LockBatchGui = new OperationCommand(o =>
    { ... }
```

---

`OperationCommand` is my `ICommand` operation which is demonstrated on my blog post entitled [Xaml: MVVM Example for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017).

How you trigger it is up to you, just remove the value of the datacontext to null then set it back.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think this is a good concept to re-establish the V/VM separation, but I still think it's unfortunate having to perform this "reset" of the DataContext/ItemsSource at all. Why is the property change notification not sufficient? Should the data grid not re-generate it's auto columns whenever I add new columns to the bound `DataTable` and trigger a notification of that change?